# Update query isn't updating records in database?

Tags: c#

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update tb1 set rollno=@rollno WHERE name=@Name", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtproject_name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rollno", textroll.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Updated sucessfully");                
}
```

This is my code for updating data in the database but it is not updating anything... why isn't it working?

Comment: Do you have some exception?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? txtprocet_name has a correct value during runtime?

Comment: put a try catch block around your code

Comment: can you show us your connection string?

Comment: no i am not having any exception and yes it is having correct value at runtime

Comment: At a guess, if you're not getting an actual error then '@Name' is probably not in your table

Answer (score 2):

Do not use named parameters, use ? instead.

[MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Answer (score 0):

Which database server you are using? there is difference passing parameters while server changes for example

SQL Server - @Name

MySql - @Name

Oracle - :Name

etc.

if you are using MS Access use as follows

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update tb1 set rollno=? WHERE name=?", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rollno", textroll.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtproject_name.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Updated sucessfully");           
}
```

for more refer
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access

Comment: if you are using MS Access use following way

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("update tb1 set roll=? where name=?",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("roll",txtrole.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name",txtname.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

Comment: @BibyAugustine You need to change position of the AddWithValue calls, check the last paragraph of the quoted documentation in my answer.

Comment: @okrumnow i think my example is best suit for this problem because here he doesn't create any parameter collection here... this will also works fine....

Comment: @user3181292 I updated my answer with link. just do refer http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access

Comment: @BibyAugustine The error is the order of the parameters. You have to add `rollno` first, because it is the value for the first ? in the query.